# How do you merge indexes of two lists in Groovy?

Tags: list, groovy

I have two lists that I need to merge into a new list, but the new list needs to contain merged indexes of the original lists. For example:

```
List1 = [1, 2, 3]
List2 = [a, b, c]
```

I need the output to be:

```
finalList = [1a, 2b, 3c]
```

I need to be able to do this in groovy. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both lists are the same size, in Groovy 2.4+,

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

assert ['1a', '2b', '3c'] == list1.withIndex().collect { it, index -> it + list2[index] }
```

Alternatively and a bit more simply in Groovy 1.5+,

```
assert ['1a', '2b', '3c'] == [list1, list2].transpose()*.sum()
```

Comment: That gets me really close. When I use that with my code, I'm getting the following:
[[1, a] , [2, b] , [3, c]]
Maybe my original lists are not set up correctly? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Not entirely certain how you're getting that - try the other method I edited in

Comment: Yeah, same result as the first option. I'm trying to make this simple, so I left out my setup. I'm using an XMLslurper to get values out of a XML schema, which I then put into a list using the .list() method. I'm doing this to create two lists. I now need to merge them. I'm not sure if that setup is preventing the solution you provided from working.

Comment: With a new groovy script, and copying in your code it works perfectly with the example you provided. This means there is something wrong with my setup in the original lists.

Comment: Not keen on `sum()` at the end, it's clever and neat, but if both input lists contain integers, it will give an unwanted result

Answer (score 0):

The following is very close to doelleri's solution:

In Groovy 2.4+

```
println ([list1, list2].transpose().collect{it -> it[0] + it[1]})
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1a, 2b, 3c]
```

Comment: Thanks Alfasin! That worked too! As a side note, I resolved my problem. The only way that both of your solutions worked was to create an array first. In groovy you can have a list and an array. As a list, this would not work. Once I converted it to an array, both solutions worked perfectly. I had to use this to convert my lists to an array: .text() as String[] 
Thank you for the help!

Comment: can you explain the last half of that code: {it -> it[0] + it[1]}) 
What does the "->" mean?

Comment: @GrantEdwards that's a lambda expression, `it` is the parameter (symbolizes each one of the items in the list that we'll iterate on) so for each item (a list with to elements) that looks like `it = [1, a]` we'll return instead: `it[0] + it[1]` which will result in string concatenation of `1` and `'a'` => `1a` in our example.